# Getting the same message while using Facepunch.Steamworks

Tags: c#, networking, steam, udp

I use Facepunch.Steamworks for P2P game made in Unity, so I send packets through it(UnreliableNoDelay sendtype), but I've got a problem, since I send message like this:
Move:0
and get this:
Move:00,994
The thing is that the previous sent message, before "Move:0" was -0,994, so there is a question:
Why do I keep getting the last non zero message(I get 00,994 even if I sent some more "Move:0" messages)?
I use the same encoding(UTF8, tried with Unicode) on both, receive and send.
I also debugged the messages(in Unity, if it is important) just before sending and just after receiving it, so it couldn't change.
I think it's because of Steamworks' way to send messages, but can't get the way to fix it(except the one, when I ignore the messages if it is equal to last one).
Also if I stop sending messages receiving is also stopped, so there is no loop, as I see.
That's the results what I get in console(1-sent, 2-received):[image]

I also get parts of another message in this one, like this for example:
[image]
"p" is from another message "Jump:0".

The code I use to send:

```
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageType+";"+message);
    Debug.Log(messageType + ";" + message);
    client.Networking.SendP2PPacket(steamId, data, data.Length, networkType, channel);
```

And to receive:

```
            client.Networking.OnP2PData = delegate (ulong steamId, byte[] bytes, int lenght, int channel)
        {
            ParseMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes), steamId);
        };
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I had to use this code to encode the data:
`Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, dataLenght)`.